# Work with integer as date in firebird sql

Tags: sql, firebird

I´m working on a system that stores its dates and times as integer in firebird sql, for whatever reason I do not understand.  Anyway, I need to do comparison with those numbers as date objects, from this script:

```
SELECT FIRST 100 a.S_ID, a.TR_SEQ, a.TR_DATE, a.TR_TIME, a.TR_TERM_SLA, r.DR_NAME, 
FROM TRANSACK a, READER r, EVENT_TYPE ev, MASTER m 
WHERE a.TR_TERM_SLA = r.T_ADDR and a.TR_EVENT = ev.ET_TYPENO and a.TR_MSTSQ = m.MST_SQ 
ORDER BY a.TR_DATE DESC
```

Now, what I would like to add to the where conditions something like this:

```
and CAST(TR_DATE as DATE) < '2013-11-19' and and CAST(TR_DATE as DATE) > '2013-11-20'
```

... the above where conditions do not work since the TR_DATE column is for integers, the format is like this '20131120', which would be today.  I guess I would have to cast to string before, then cast to date, or some such gymnastic exercises.

Is there in fact a way for me to use TR_DATE as date object after some sort of conversion?

Comment: Can you change your integral date to something more sensible like epoch seconds?

Comment: Actually @pilcrow I got an answer from ain, of course I should have used comparison on the integers.  I actually was thinking on using epoch but wasn´t there yet  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the "integer date" is in the `yyyymmdd` format you can compare them safely. So instead of converting them to date convert your date to integer in the same format: `'2013-11-19'` as integer would be `20131119` and thus

```
and TR_DATE < 20131119 and TR_DATE > 20131120
```

It is possible to convert the integer to real date type but that would be much more work.

Comment: Haha!  I can´t belive I didn´t see that one!  Thanx, worked like a charm  :)